# How to preserve newlines in a textarea when passing by POST?

Tags: javascript, php, newline

In my web page, I am passing the value of a `textarea` to PHP via the `POST` Method.  That value is supposed to be written into a file, but in the `$_POST` key which contains the value, it has no line breaks, so when it is written to the file, there are no line breaks (as if some one replaced `\n` with nothing).

Is there some PHP/JS function that replaces JS textarea newlines into PHP newlines that work in files?

#### Edit:

My code is supposed to be a file editor.  Here it is:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>File Editor</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
        <style>h1{text-align:center;font-size:40px;padding:10px;border:2px solid black;border-radius:10px;}textarea{width:90%;height:90%}</style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>File Editor</h1>
        <?php
        if(isset($_POST["save"],$_POST["extra"]))
          file_put_contents($_POST["save"],$_POST["extra"]);
        if(isset($_POST["delete"]))
          unlink($_POST["delete"]);
        if(!isset($_POST["filename"],$_POST["submit"])){
        ?>
        <form action="editor.php" method="post">
            <label for="filename" id="n">Enter a file to edit: </label>
            <input type="text" name="filename" placeholder="Enter file name to edit"/>
            <button type="submit" name="submit">Submit</button>
        </form>
        <?php }else{ ?>
        <textarea><?php echo htmlspecialchars(file_get_contents($_POST["filename"])); ?></textarea>
        <span style="display:none"><?php echo $_POST["filename"]; ?></span>
        <form action="editor.php" method="post" style="display:none" id="a">
            <input name="close" id="v" />
            <input name="extra" id="e" />
        </form><br/>
        <button id="save">Save</button>
        <button id="close">Close file</button>
        <button id="delete" style="color:red">Delete file</button>
        <script>
            function submit(v,x,c){
                document.getElementById("v").name=v;
                document.getElementById("v").value=x;
                document.getElementById("e").value=c;
                document.getElementById("a").submit();
            }
            document.getElementById("save").onclick=function(){
                submit("save",document.getElementsByTagName("span")[0].innerHTML,document.getElementsByTagName("textarea")[0].value.replace(/\n/g,"\r\n"));
            }
            document.getElementById("close").onclick=function(){submit("close");}
            document.getElementById("delete").onclick=function(){
                if(confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this file?"))submit("delete",document.getElementsByTagName("span")[0].innerHTML);
            }
        </script><br/><br/>
        <?php } ?> </body>
</html>
```

Comment: If you're on windows, you might have to replace all `\n` with `\r\n`.

Comment: @TimothéMalahieude : I just tried `textarea.value.replace(/\n/g,"\r\n");` but it doesn't seem to work.  Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: How are you reading the $_POST data? How are you writing it into your file. Provide some code. `file_put_contents('foo.txt', $_POST['bar'])` should work as expected. If it does not, are you using a special js textarea?

Comment: Hmm can you post you code?

Comment: @JensV : Nope, I am using a normal textarea.

Comment: @LakshyaRaj did you open the file which was written? It should contain the newlines. HTML will not display those newlines though. You need to replace them with `<br>` for example

Comment: **Beware of putting this code on the internet** the current code allows to upload and overwrite arbitrary files on the server! By allowing to modify the filename directly they are able to write to any location, including overwriting your source files which leads to remote code execution!

Comment: @JensV : When I opened the file, I did not see `\n` in it.  Also, I made this specially for just me and someone else who I can trust so I think it's fine.  It was made to edit PHP files which you can't see the source of.  It's local on my device.

Comment: Did you try replacing `htmlspecialchars(file_get_contents($_POST["filename"]));` with `str_replace("\n", "<br>", htmlspecialchars(file_get_contents($_POST["filename"])));`

Comment: @JensV : I can output it to the web page just fine, but the problem comes when I try to output it into the file, so I don't think replacing `\n` with `<br/>` will be that helpful.  When I look into my file, there are no newlines, so it isn't the fault of the textarea.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226752/discussion-between-lakshya-raj-and-jensv).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see that the purpose of your javascript code is only to fill in any input values. This can be done by utilizing `<form>` directly. Most likely, copying your data into a `<input tye="text">` (text is the default type) will mangle your newlines.

Something like this should be equivalent and without the presented issue:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>File Editor</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
        <style>h1{text-align:center;font-size:40px;padding:10px;border:2px solid black;border-radius:10px;}textarea{width:90%;height:90%}</style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>File Editor</h1>
<?php
if(isset($_POST["save"],$_POST["extra"]))
    file_put_contents($_POST["filename"],$_POST["extra"]);
if(isset($_POST["delete"]))
    unlink($_POST["filename"]);
if(!isset($_POST["filename"],$_POST["submit"])){
?>
<form action="editor.php" method="post">
    <label for="filename" id="n">Enter a file to edit: </label>
    <input type="text" name="filename" placeholder="Enter file name to edit"/>
    <button type="submit" name="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
<?php }else{ ?>
<span style="display:none"><?php echo $_POST["filename"]; ?></span>
<form action="editor.php" method="post">
    <textarea name="extra"><?php echo htmlspecialchars(file_get_contents($_POST["filename"])); ?></textarea>
    <br/>
    <input type="hidden" name="filename" value="<?= $_POST['filename'] ?>">
    <button name="save">Save</button>
    <button name="close">Close file</button>
    <button name="delete" style="color:red">Delete file</button>
</form>
<script>
    document.getElementById("delete").onclick=function(e){
        if(!confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this file?")) e.preventDefault();
    }
</script>
<br/><br/>
<?php } ?> 
    </body>
</html>
```

Also as mentioned, you will probably need to format the newlines for html when displaying.

---

When needing to pass the same or hidden data you can use `<input type="hidden" name=".." value="..">`. This is used to pass the filename. The desired action is passed with the button press. The name of button you press will be passed in the request.

Answer (score 0):

In your PHP code, you can do:

```
$text = nl2br($_POST['name_of_textarea']);
```

Then save `$text` into the file.

This will preserve line breaks.

Comment: That preserves line breaks _in the webpage_, but the problem occurs when I output to the file.

Comment: Just tried, doesn't work.  Anyways, the solution by JensV works.  Thanks anyways!